# trying to calculate a formula in cell

Tags: microsoft-excel

Hello I am trying to calculate a column of formulas involving 3 different calculations but am having difficulty in creating the formula to give me the correct answer.

[image]

What this table shows is Fund A has a portfolio weight of 4.4% and the return of this Fund was 2.96%. What is the contribution Fund A produced as part of the overall contribution return of 2.66% in cell D2. This is repeated all the way down column D until all the contribution values equal 2.66% NOTE the total in B19 equals 100% being the total of the portfolio weight

I am trying to calculate the cell formulas in the Column D (CONT%) to add up to and equal 2.66% as per the total of return in the Return column. The calculation has to include the weight % in column B as well as the negative returns must be a negative contribution.
If you can help me that would be wonderful and much appreciated
Murray

Comment: I think it will be a formula like `=SUMPRODUCT(B2:B10*(C2:C10+1))-1`. However as you didn't included editable data I can't test it.

Comment: @murray, could you share with us what formula you have applied in `D2` & for `Total to get 2.66%` and you are expecting `100%` instead of `2.66%`, write !!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the weight is the percentage of the total portfolio invested in that fund, then here is how I figure it.

```
|    |   A   |    B   |    C   |    D   | E |        F       |     G     |   H   |
|:--:|:-----:|:------:|:------:|:------:|:-:|:--------------:|:---------:|:-----:|
| 1  | Fund  | Weight | Return | Cont%  |   | Weight $ ($1M) | Return $  |       |
| 2  | A     | 4.4%   | 2.96%  | 0.13%  |   | 44,000         | 1,302.40  |       |
| 3  | B     | 6.6%   | 7.33%  | 0.48%  |   | 66,000         | 4,837.80  |       |
| 4  | C     | 4.0%   | -0.28% | -0.01% |   | 40,000         | -112.00   |       |
| 5  | D     | 5.2%   | 5.75%  | 0.30%  |   | 52,000         | 2,990.00  |       |
| 6  | E     | 3.6%   | 3.07%  | 0.11%  |   | 36,000         | 1,105.20  |       |
| 7  | F     | 4.3%   | 6.11%  | 0.26%  |   | 43,000         | 2,627.30  |       |
| 8  | G     | 4.3%   | -1.47% | -0.06% |   | 43,000         | -632.10   |       |
| 9  | I     | 7.4%   | 0.96%  | 0.07%  |   | 74,000         | 710.40    |       |
| 10 | J     | 7.8%   | 3.56%  | 0.28%  |   | 78,000         | 2,776.80  |       |
| 11 | K     | 8.0%   | 0.46%  | 0.04%  |   | 80,000         | 368.00    |       |
| 12 | L     | 6.9%   | 2.74%  | 0.19%  |   | 69,000         | 1,890.60  |       |
| 13 | M     | 8.4%   | -0.15% | -0.01% |   | 84,000         | -126.00   |       |
| 14 | N     | 7.5%   | 4.81%  | 0.36%  |   | 75,000         | 3,607.50  |       |
| 15 | O     | 6.9%   | 3.39%  | 0.23%  |   | 69,000         | 2,339.10  |       |
| 16 | P     | 7.6%   | 2.63%  | 0.20%  |   | 76,000         | 1,998.80  |       |
| 17 | Q     | 6.9%   | 0.73%  | 0.05%  |   | 69,000         | 503.70    |       |
| 18 | R     | 0.2%   | 0.00%  | 0.00%  |   | 2,000          | 0.00      |       |
| 19 | Total | 100.0% | 2.66%  | 2.62%  |   | 1,000,000      | 26,187.50 | 2.62% |
```

The formula in `D2` is simply `=B2*C2`.  However, I came up with 2.62% instead of 2.66%.

In columns `F` through `H` I ran a double check of how much was invested in each fund (if the total portfolio was $1M) and the returned dollars for the fund.  As you can see, when I total that up it also comes up to 2.62% so I'm not sure how you computed the 2.66%.  I noticed that the Fund letters skip `H`.  If that is missing, then that could skew the number.  If instead I've made a wrong assumption about what you mean by `Weight` then you need to define that.

Answer (score 0):

If the value for in the "Total" line (19) for column C is the sum of all items divided by the number of items, the "2.66" is flat wrong and one hopes is some kind of typo after obtaining the original data and before taking the screenshot of it.

If it is the sum of the column entries divided by the number of non-zero entries, then it fits:  42.6/16 = 2.6625 and rounds to 2.66.

Why that would be done would be a great question so...

It could be coincidence... We have a word for that because they happen. After all, typing "2.6...6 instead of "2.6...2" would be easy. But... why any typos at all because why any typing at all? So maybe not so easy.

Also, it is not rounding of the "Cont%" values vs. the "Return $" values as that actually comes out to less than 2.62 (as evidenced by the $26,187.50 vs. a $26,200.00 sum for the dollar returns).

My bet, then, is on either a typo of unexpected provenance, or a division by 16, not 17.